# CSS Flexbox issue with aligning children using `align-self`

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's the test code - https://jsfiddle.net/8dgeh9r3/1/

I am simulating two cases. In the first case, there is a main parent flex container which has several intermediate parents (also flex boxes that inherit from the top), followed lastly by a child item. The main parent sets `align-items` to `flex-start` but the last child should have `align-self` to `flex-end`. That does not seem to be happening.

I wrote a second case where there are no intermediate parents. Just the main parent and it's single child item. Again, the flex styles don't seem to work.

**NOTE: I want the child item(s) to align horizontally along the axis (left to right)**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want to align horizontally the first item but align-self is a property which align items vertically. To set horizontal alignements you have to use [justify-content](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) property on container. You can also play with margins.

Comment: Good answer!. But, to be more accurate, speak of "along main axis" and "across main axis"

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to resolve this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Louis Serre in his answer:

> you want to align horizontally the first item but align-self is a property which align items vertically.

As such, to achieve the effect you wanted, change the `flex-direction` to `column`...**at least for Case 2**. Case 1 may need more thought.

```css
.parent1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 90%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.child1 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: orange;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!-- case 2: Single parent -->
<div class='parent1'>
  <div class='child1'>
    <p>This is item 1</p>
  </div>
  <!--<div class='child1'><p>This is item 2</p></div>-->
</div>
```

**Note: this change may have knock on effects so it will depend upon the overall design as to whether it is the optimal solution for you.**

Comment: That does give the desired effect. But what I don't understand is that why is the "flex-direction" columnar when I want the children to lay out horizontally (left to right)?
Case 1 is what I am trying to achieve in the end.

Comment: It's because you're using `align-items` to lay out the content. What I suspect you want is `justify-content`. - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/